Convertir Blazor Web App en PWA, no genera fichero service-worker-assets.js
Tengo una aplicación Blazor Web App que la he convertido en PWA con esté video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdVJXP1nDU4
Básicamente, he cogido una aplicación Wasm, y he copiado los ficheros:

manifest.json
icon-192.png
icon-512.png
service-worker.js (y publihed)
en mi aplicación Blazor Web app
He modificado mi app.razor, añadiendo la linea en el bodynavigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');


Y he modificado la configuración del proyecto server
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
    </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GestionCasaMadre.Client\GestionCasaMadre.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GestionCasaMadre.Shared\GestionCasaMadre.Shared.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.7.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

La aplicación arranca, cero errores, y se puede instalar, arranca el servicio service-worker.js.
El problema es que no me genera el fichero service-worker-assets.js y lo necesito para poder borrar la cache y poder actualizar.
Alguien sabe por qué no se genera?
Gracias
